# Python DataFrame: how to delete rows where more than one column is populated?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe in which the columns are supposed to be dummy columns (for each row only one column should be populated). However, the data has some 'noise' in it: some rows have more than one column populated. I want to drop these rows.

Suppose the DataFrame looks like the below example:

```
  a       b        c        d  
0 NaN     1        NaN      NaN
1 1       2        3        4  
2 1       1        NaN      NaN 
3 NaN     NaN      1        NaN
4 1       NaN      1        NaN
```

So my expected result is that rows [1,2,4] get dropped. You may say that I only accept rows where the number of NaN values is equal to the number_of_columns - 1.

Is there any way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will get you there.  You just count the number of nulls in a row and slice your frame based on that.

```
df[df.notna().sum(axis=1) <= 1]
    a    b    c   d
0 NaN  1.0  NaN NaN
3 NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a perfect solution that also allows you to drop rows based on a subset of column from your dataframe!

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df[(df.shape[1]-1)==(df.isna().sum(axis=1))]
```

---

```
    a    b    c   d
0 NaN  1.0  NaN NaN
3 NaN  NaN  1.0 NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the above! And supposing my data has more columns and I want to drop rows based only on the above subset of columns, how would you go about it?

Comment: @Maciej if I understand , you can create a copy, `m=df.loc[:,[interested_columns]].copy()` and then replace the `df` in the code with `m`.